# How can I make a floated div fill up the remaining width?

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have a div which has `float: left`, and a div which has `float: right`. The div which has `float: left` has a width of `50px`, while the div which has `float: right` should take up the remaining horizontal space in the parent div.

How can I accomplish this with CSS?

Comment: Trying using `margin-left:60px` without using `float` in the right div

Comment: @mshsayem Oh, hey, that works. Post that as an answer, and the award's yours.

Comment: you can also put the floating div inside div "right". But I prefer @mshsayem's solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `margin-left:60px` (or whatever width your left div could be) without using `float` in the right div. See related fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/CKcQH/

CSS:

```
.leftDiv
{
    width:50px;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.rightDiv
{
    margin-left:55px; /* Compute total width of leftDiv */
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

Html:

```
<div>
    <div class="leftDiv">
        My content on left
    </div>
    <div class="rightDiv">
        My content on right should take all the space the parent has (after excluding the space on the left)
    </div>
</div>
```